# Jquery Ajax load a div inside a file

Tags: jquery

I try to load with jQuery and Ajax a div that is in another file. I can load the hole file, I can load a div with a text inside that file, but I cannot load a simple div alone. Why?

index.html:

```
$(function(){
   $("#linkajax").click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $("#target").load("extern.html #red");   
   });
})
```

This works:

```
$("#target").load("extern.html");
$("#target").load("extern.html #text1");
```

This does not work:

```
$("#target").load("extern.html #red");
```

extern.html:

```
<div id="text1"> text </div>
<div id="red"> </div>

#text1 {
    position: absolute;
    top:200px; left:200px;
}

#red {
    position: absolute;
    top:50px; left:50px;
    width:100px; height:100px;
    background:red;
}
```

This is extern.html: http://jsfiddle.net/RWLeB/

Comment: Try to put some content in red div? You load empty div, load is working, actually. And, css should be on index.html. (css from external file aren't applied, since you load just part of the page).

Comment: Yes! your are right, this is the point. It loads the div but not the css.

Comment: You should put that comment as an answer. I would accept it and this question would be closed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The red div should have some content in it. CSS, however, should be placed on index.html file. CSS from external file can't be applied, since you load just one part of external page (#red).

Answer (score 0):

if below code works..

```
$("#target").load("extern.html #text1");
```

then #red also should work

```
$("#target").load("extern.html #red");
```

This would have loaded the div inside your target,since you dont have any data you not able to see anything

small change in #red css and check

```
#red {
    position: absolute;
    top:50px; left:50px;
    width:100px; height:100px;
    background-color:red;
}
```

Hope it helps..